# How to read large text file and break it into batches for processing?

Tags: c#, text-files, batch-processing

I have a large text file that contains GUIDs that I will use to load into the Custom Application that I am trying to create.  Since the file is so large (may contain millions of lines of GUIDs), I want to break it into parts and process each part and then move to the next part afterwwards until the end of the file.

Example of text file

> ```
> ASDFSADFJO23490234AJSDFKL
> JOGIJO349230420GJDGJDO230
> BJCIOJDFOBJOD239402390423
> JFWEIOJFOWE2390423901230N
> 3490FJSDOFOIWEMO23MOFI23O
> FJWEIOFJWEIOFJOI23J230022
> ```

Lets just say, the text file has 99,000 lines and I want to process the first 10,000 values (repeat until the end).  I will create a new folder for the first batch of 10,000 using like a DateTime.Now as the folder name.  Then, the 10,000 values will each have a file created using its value name as the file name.  After the first 10,000 values are done, I will create a new folder using DateTime.Now again and move onto the next 10,000 values in the text file.  Repeat until the end of the file.

I am able to read the text file, create a folder with the DateTime.Now, create the file with the appropriate name, but I do not know how to batch process the list of values from the text file.

This is how I am reading the file.

```
string[] source = new string[] {}; 
source = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\guids.txt");
```

I tried to use the Skip/Take method, and I think it works? but I just do not know how to create a new folder and add the new subset to it.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  I am open to suggestions and can help clarify if you need more details.  Thanks!!

Comment: If you're able to read the entire file, then why do you want to batch the processing?

Comment: The reason why I want to batch is because when I create the files into the folder (on a Windows Server), I do not want to have all the objects in that one folder.  It will be very memory and processing intensive on the server if I have millions of objects in 1 folder.

Comment: what you are wanting to do does not sound too difficult I would 1st understand how to read and or split the file if necessary 2nd determine if you want to use a While Loop or a foreach loop and then set up the logic to create the files and folder based on a Counter.. when the counter hits a specific count ..then you know it's time to reset the counter..this will require a nested foreach loop in my opinion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, I deduce that your problem is not in fact "how do I batch the reads from guid.txt?", but "how do I process these guids and create files in groups of ten thousands in separate folders".
With this in mind, here's an example of how you could do that.

```
var batchSize = 10000;
var source = File.ReadLines(@"C:\guids.txt");
var i = 0;
var currentDirPath = "";
foreach (var line in source)
{
    if (i % batchSize == 0)
    {
        currentDirPath = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(currentDirPath);
    }
    var newFile = Path.Combine(currentDirPath, line + ".txt");
    File.WriteAllText(newFile, "Some content");
    i++;
}
```

Avoid using DateTime for file or folder names. The odds that some unforeseen behavior makes your code try to write to a file that already exists is just too high.

EDIT: About parallelism: use it only if you need it. It is *always* more complex than it seems, and it has a tendency to introduce hard to find bungs. That being said, here is an **untested** idea.

```
//Make sure the current folder is empty, otherwise the folders are very likely to already exist.
if (Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Any())
{
    throw new IOException("Current directory is not empty.");
}

var batchSize = 10000;
var source = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\guids.txt");

//Create the folders synchronoulsy to avoid race conditions.
var batchCount = (source.Length/batchSize) + 1;
for (int i = 0; i < batchCount; i++)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(i.ToString());
}

source.AsParallel().ForAll(line =>
{
    var folder = ((int)(Array.IndexOf(source, line) / batchSize)).ToString();
    var newFile = Path.Combine(folder.ToString(), line + ".txt");
    File.WriteAllText(newFile, "Some content");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Guillaume!  Your code work.  Sorry for the confusion in the description, I suppose I did not choose the right words to describe my issue (sounded okay to me).  From the previous post, someone mentioned Parallel method.  Would you happen to know how to do that as well?  I looked up Parallel, but still new to C# so I was a bit confused.

Comment: @Jayarikahs I added some parallel code, but I didn't test it. Let me know how it works!

Comment: I created a small test text file (contains 15 values, so 15 lines) and it errors out at File.WriteAllText (Could not find part of the path C:\zz\8\09.txt)  It does create 8 folders (names 0-7) and it creates 1 file per folder.  I changed the source.Length/10000 to source.Length/2

Comment: @Jayarikahs Yeah I see the error. I create batchCount folders, and then the parallel code figures out the index of the line and divides it by batchCount to figure out where to write the file. I forgot to divide by batchCount.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume!  It works perfectly.  I am stepping through your working code and am able to see how the Parallel works.  Many thanks for your help in teaching me.  It runs pretty fast too.